# document.body.innerHTML issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal, innerhtml

I have an email converter on a website that was written by another developer that takes a person’s user name and formats it to an email address.
If you type on a page [[username]] it will generate a clickable email address on the webpage: username@gmail.com

Now I am trying to incorporate PayPal’s skip to accessibility navigation to the website. 
After I add the code for Pay Pal, when I press tab the "Skip to" link appears at the top left, but the link doesn’t work. Meaning the dropdown menu will not appear. 
https://github.com/paypal/skipto

In my javascript email converter there is a  code line

document.body.innerHTML = emailConvert(document.body.innerHTML);

This seems to be the the issue, because the Paypal code also is using innerHTML in their code as well.
I’m looking for a solution for this specific line of code or all of the code

document.body.innerHTML = emailConvert(document.body.innerHTML);

I have tried various solutions with no results. Any help would be great.
Here is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   (function () { 
     var domains = { 'n': 'gmail.com', 'p': 'yahoo.com', 's': 'comcast.net',    'k': 'att.net', 'b': 'aol.com', 'i': 'sbcglobal.net' };
    function renderEmail(str, user, domain, text) {
        var email = (user.match(/@/)) ? user : user + "@" + (domain || domains["n"]);
        if (domains[user.toLowerCase()]) { email = domain + "@" + domains[user.toLowerCase()]; }
        return " <a href='mailto:" + email + "?Subject=" + document.title + "\"'>" + (text || email) + "</a>";
    }
    function emailConvert(source) { return source.replace(/\[\[\s*([^\  [\,\|]*)\|?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)?\s*()\]\]/g, renderEmail).replace(/\[\[\s*([^\[\,\|]*)\|?\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)?\s*\,{1}\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\]/g, renderEmail); }
    document.body.innerHTML = emailConvert(document.body.innerHTML);
    $.fn.emailConverter = function () { this.innerHTML = emailConvert($(this).html(emailConvert($(this).html()))); }
})();
```

});

Comment: Nevermind, I see you just edited it. -- You can select your code in the editor and then click the code icon in the toolbar ( the brackets icon: {} ), makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` gives you a string representation of the HTML within an element. It doesn't capture event handlers that were attached to those elements programmatically, since those aren't represented in the HTML.

Don't overwrite the `innerHTML` of `document.body`. That's like telling your secretary to write something down, and s/he instead grabs everything on your desk, hurls it out the window, then scrawls the desired note directly on your desktop. Even if the secretary draws a very accurate picture of your phone on the desk, you shouldn't be surprised when it doesn't work.

Okay, not a perfect metaphor, but hopefully you get my meaning.

Instead, you should find the specific HTML element(s) you want to modify, and/or insert new HTML elements at the desired locations.

There are lots of different methods by which you can grab an existing element on the page, such as  `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelector`, `document.querySelectorAll`, and `document.getElementsByTagName`. You can also drill down into the child nodes of `document.body` if you want to obsessively check all the elements on the page.

Similarly, there are also multiple way to insert HTML into an HTML element once you've selected it, including both `appendChild` and `insertAdjacentHTML`. You can still manipulate the `innerHTML` of a specific element, but you should be careful about overwriting any child nodes it might contain, especially if those child nodes might have event listeners.